# Tumblr theme doesn't link to dashboard

Tags: tumblr

I'm using the Oblivion Tumblr theme and it's perfect except that at the top, where all of the other themes have the link back to your dashboard, this one doesn't, and it doesn't have the customization button at the top either, so I'm not even sure it has the follow/unfollow button.

Is there a way to manually add it on or will I just have to use another theme?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the author's theme.

The author released a fix a couple of days ago.

The updated theme is on <strike>the author's [site](http://www.miguelmota.com/portfolio/oblivion/oblivion-v1.2.1.txt)</strike> [GitHub](https://github.com/miguelmota/oblivion-theme) you will need to copy the updated theme code into the Edit HTML area.

**EDIT: The theme has been moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/miguelmota/oblivion-theme) however, as of 2012 it is no longer being maintained.**

[image: Edit Html in Customize Appearance page]

[image: Paste html in this section]